# settings_schema.json in Shopify - adding and deleting fields

Tags: jquery, json, shopify

I have a `settings_schema.json` file in a Shopify store that contains data pertaining to text fields for a Q&A type section of the site. A snippet of the file is below:

`...
  {
    "name": "FAQs",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Shopping"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "faq_dropdown_text_shopping_q1",
        "label": "Shopping Question Dropdown 1"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "faq_dropdown_text_shopping_a1",
        "label": "Shopping Answer Dropdown 1"
      }
...and so on`

I want to use this file to populate a jQuery based dropdown menu - is it possible to add a parameter in this file to give the CMS user an option to add/delete fields?

My preliminary research has lead me here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema which sadly doesn't indicate that there is an add/delete feature for textareas but was curious if anyone here has done a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation reveals that a section needs to be created, and you need to use blocks.

https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/sections#blocks